# android.widget.TabHost at the bottom and Action bar at the top together

Tags: android

I know the tabhost and tabwidget is deprecated but I have a design where I need to have a Tabhost with tabwidget to launch different activities with tab selection. With this , I also need to have an Action bar at the top depicting normal android's option's menu with search icon and so. Can anyone please provide me with example which is doing this.

So requirements are
1) Tabhost at bottom to launch separate activities with each tab
2) The common action bar for all tabhost's child activities showing options menu.

TIA.

Comment: Someone might be interested to take this project as a Freelancing project!

Comment: I want to implement this myself. I tried using tabhost but in the activities I launch using tabhost, I get getActionbar() as null .:(